# Comparing columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two text columns from different DataFrames that I want to compare and generate a new csv file with the columns and a new Boolean one that will say True if the columns match and False if they don't. 
My code is:

```
val1 = df1['val1']
val2 = df1['val2']
val11 = df2['val11']
val22 = df2['val22']

SameOrNot = None
if val1 == val11 and val2 == val22:
    SameOrNot = True
else:
    SameOrNot = False

pd.to_csv('output.csv', header = [val1, val2, val11, val22, SameOrNot])
```

I get an error though: **ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare**

Do you have any ideas? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if val1.values == val11.values and val2.values == val22.values
```